# Zapier Webhook issue

Tags: webhooks, zapier

I've set up a ZAP so that when a subscriber is added to my aweber email list they are automatically added to a product in my membership plugin called DAP or digital access pass.

As per the instructions of the membership plugins developers, I am using a webhook in the zapier 'post' section.

It's not working. Quite simply the webhook doesn't appear to be calling anything.

Now, weird thing is that zapier logs show the webhook has been sent and has had success. But from DAP's end nothing is being received.

The support team at DAP tell me that the script isn't being called, because nothing appears in their logs.

They show me this by putting the webhook URL into a browser and calling it that way, and THEN the relevant info arrives in the DAP logs.

Zapier told me they do not trouble shoot and so advised that I post here.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test if Zapier is making a call or not by sending the request to http://requestb.in

Steps:

1. Create a request bin and copy the URL.
   [Request bin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCawj.png)
2. In Zapier, replace the webhooks post URL with the requestb.in URL.
3. Now, whenever the Webhook makes a post request, you should be able to visit the inspect page of your bin and check if a request was received. Just add `?inspect` to the end of the URL. For example, if your Request bin URL is `https://requestb.in/wbto8jwb` then you should visit `https://requestb.in/wbto8jwb?inspect`
4. The inspect page will show all the requests received.

With this, you will know if Zapier is sending the requests. If the requests are being received by request bin then there is something which needs to be fixed by DAP.

Note that it could also be something in the configuration of the Webhook that is causing the request to not be recognised by DAP. It will help if you add more details to your question - what format is the DAP team expecting to receive the data in?

Below is a sample Webhook implementation in Zapier.
I have added a hook to POST data to a request bin (https://requestb.in/wbto8jwb)
[Webhook POST screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk2R2.png)
When I test this step, the request is received in the Request Bin Inspect page (https://requestb.in/wbto8jwb?inspect).
[Request Bin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3ihD.png)

More reading:
https://zapier.com/help/webhooks/

**Update:**

You can also make a direct call to the DAP API by using a tool like https://www.hurl.it/. From the drop down in destination, select POST and put the URL here. Click on Add body and paste the raw data from request bin. Now ask the DAP team to check if the request was received.

Comment: @dan-lyons Dan you might want to put that in as a comment and not an answer. From what it looks like, Zapier is making the request, therefore the DAP team should receive the URL. 

I would also recommend deleting the Zapier screenshot, it has your secret key and you should guard this as you guard your password. You risk the chance of being hacked, I recommend getting the secret changed, if that is possible.

I've updated my answer. If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and select it as correct (info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to go through those things.

So I've done steps 1 - 4. But I have no idea what I'm looking at here in the inspect section (screenshot link below). The raw body comes back in green and so it looks as though it has been received. Would you mind telling me what I should be looking at as I'm a total amateur.


So in answer to your question - the DAP team are expecting to receive the data as a json I believe. Here are the settings they filled out in the ZAP if this helps with more detail:



Many thanks!

Dan

Comment: Unfortunately, [requestb.in](https://requestb.in/) was discontinued [2 days after](https://github.com/Runscope/requestbin/commit/8ca17a8ed7f603864329391f4be131c4b3355aaf) this answer was posted.

I'd suggest [webhookinbox.com](http://webhookinbox.com/) except they don't support HTTPS... which is probably fine for data going onto a publicly viewable page anyway.  

Comment: Thanks guys. So we've made SOME progress on this. DAP now gets the webhook OK BUT not all information is being sent:

Comment: 2018-04-02 04:23:44:DAPCONNECT: ENTER
2018-04-02 04:23:44:Running securityCheck
2018-04-02 04:23:44:customIPNHandler: secretKey=4853581658970323
2018-04-02 04:23:44:customIPNHandler: productId=53
** 2018-04-02 04:23:44:customIPNHandler.php: email=
**2018-04-02 04:23:44:customIPNHandler.php: contact__Email=

Comment: The 'email' and 'contact_Email' fields hit digital access passes logs with nothing in them. This is despite me setting up the post settings in zap as follows: https://screencast.com/t/dVcSTlxQRyhs    . WOuld very much appreciate any help on this. The webhooks PRODUCT ID we want to add them to makes it across as does the secret key. Just not the customer info. Thank you - Dan

Comment: @dan-lyons you will need to fill the text box on the left with the `key` name like `email` and the box on the right should have the `value` from your previous step in Zapier. To add another name or email, you will need to add another `key-value` pair by clicking the + icon.

Comment: Thank you @KayCee you mean like this? https://screencast.com/t/6snuVgWppjBw   --- When I did a test with this change DAP threw up this error in their logs, "2018-04-02 06:58:14:customIPNHandler: Missing payer email. Can't process the webhook/IPN. DAP expects the buyer's 'email' to be in a field called 'email' in the Array params." Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @dan-lyons Yes. It will really help if you can get some API documentation or at least a sample request for DAP. I&#39;m guessing they need something like this - https://photos.app.goo.gl/tttBTrm47H4w5SpT2

Comment: @KayCee - here is the webhook without the secret key of course - https://scrapbookingcoach.com/dap/dapconnect-shopify.php?productId=53&secretKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: this is what shows up in the DAP logs when I test the webhook:https://screencast.com/t/0YqDgCBC

Comment: Could you ask the DAP team for this? This doesn't have the data you need to send to them. The sample request will clearly have an email field either in the query params like I showed just above or in the request body as JSON or other formats like the key-value pairs.

Comment: Nevermind, I found their documentation. Taking a look - http://digitalaccesspass.com/doc/dapconnect-and-zapier-integration/

Comment: @dan-lyons You will just need to set the URL, like you shared earlier. Change the payload type to 'Form'. You don't need to change anything else in the Webhook step. You will need to then map the fields as per the `Use the DAP log` section. Let me know if that gets it to work. Upvote and mark the answer as correct if it helps.